# API.MercadoPago, obtener json sin límites

Tags: json, api, mercadopago

Qué tal, buen día a todos!

Estoy tratando de obtener un resultado en JSON de todos los movimientos dentro de una cuenta en MercadoPago tal como se ve en la imagen a continuación pero sólo me devuelve 30 de 150. Yo estoy ejecutando:

https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/search?

Y veo el límite de 30 pero no sé como agregar el parámetro para que pueda acceder a la totalidad.

¿Podrían ayudarme? Gracias!

Comment: Solo se pueden obtener los pagos de los últimos 8 meses.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que MercadoPago entrega los resultados de forma paginada, para obtener resultados de distintas paginas puedes usar los siguientes parámetros:

```
limit      | numero de pagos por página.
offset     | pago inicial de donde parte la nueva paginación. 
total      | total de pagos
```

### Ejemplo:

**Pagina 1:**  /v1/payments/search?limit=30&offset=0

- limit: 30
- offset: 0
- total: 150

**Pagina 2:** /v1/payments/search?limit=30&offset=30

- limit: 30
- offset: 30
- total: 150